# Instantiating directly vs JNDI lookup

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I've implemented EJB 2.0 session beans as POJOs behind an EJB facade.

I wish to get a reference to Bean B from Bean A. Should I:

a. Use ejb-ref and perform a JNDI lookup

b. Instantiate an instance of B directly(since it's a POJO)

Both would give me the same result. What are the pros and cons of each method? Why should I choose one over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never instantiate managed objects yourself. You should perform a lookup.
EJB 2.0 are far from POJOs. EJB 3.x are POJOs but again you would never instantiate them yourself because of many reasons.

Comment: Transaction management that would never work, injections that would never work etc. They are just not meant to be instantiated by the developer when they are marked as EJBs. If you don't want an EJB don't mark it as EJB.

Comment: Specifically, the reference returned from the lookup will be a proxy rather than a direct reference to the bean class.  The proxy is what allows all the behaviors of EJBs to be implemented: instance pooling, remoting, transactions, security, dependency injection, lifecycle management, etc.